# Heroku is unable to install the dependencies in my "requirements.txt" when pushing my django project

Tags: python, django, heroku

Whenever I try pushing my Django project to Heroku, I see errors referring to the dependencies listed in my "requirements.txt" file(for example:

```
Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r 
/tmp/build_45e030bb239f553887437d4bfa754b90/requirements.txt (line 
2))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the 
requirement anaconda-client==1.6.9 (from -r 
/tmp/build_45e030bb239f553887437d4bfa754b90/requirements.txt (line 
2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for anaconda- 
client==1.6.9 (from -r 
/tmp/build_45e030bb239f553887437d4bfa754b90/requirements.txt (line 
2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I should note that I forgot to setup a virtual environment before creating my project(I'm just beginning to see what a big mistake that may have been). Could this be what's causing me problems? Is it too late to set up a virtual environment now that the project has been completed and is ready for production? If that isn't the problem, do I maybe need to update or install something? I apologize if this has already been answered or if its a stupid question, but Heroku support was unable to help me out and I wasn't able to find a solution on here. Any input or suggestions would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: No, not too late.  I'd create the virtual env and start with nothing in it except django.  Then keep running your app until you've pip installed all dependencies.  The concern with doing it otherwise is that you may be trying to load every python package you've ever installed.  If you live in the venv then its really easy to pip freeze >> requirements.txt and it makes it easier to troubleshoot.  Some libraries are more difficult to build depending on the os.  In AWS I needed to install some dependencies with yum.

Comment: Your problem is that there is no `1.6.9` version of `anaconda-client` on PyPI (which `pip` uses): https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/#history

Comment: Seems you're both right. Going to try what @sahutchi suggested as it seems that Heroku is in fact trying to download every package I've ever installed. Valuable lesson learned, always set up a virtual environment first. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I would also add that using a separate conda env causes the same issue when using 'pip freeze > requirements.txt' to populate the requirements.txt file; many unnecessary packages. You can either delete each individual package and commit the changes each time, or start with a trimmed down requirements.txt file, like from here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip